# Deploying Ossec HIDS Windows Agent via GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, ossec

I am trying to deploy OSSEC agent to about 100 Windows 7 boxes through GPO on our AD.  I understand that I need to create and MSI from the EXE and import the specific client.keys file for the windows box.  I was wondering if anyone has done this and if they could offer any helpful advice for accomplishing this task.

Comment: What is your exact problem? Yuor question is too broad.

Comment: The exact problem is: "I need to create an MSI that can be deployed by GPO from a bare EXE. How can I do this?"

Answer (score 1):

This can be now be accomplished via auto-ossec - https://github.com/BinaryDefense/auto-ossec

Download the WiX Toolset binaries and use the wxs\Create-AutoOssecMsi.ps1 to create the MSI file for deployment via GPO.

Answer (score -2):

You use Wininstall to convert Ossec from exe to msi include IP server ossec in file msi. 
Deployment ossec.msi from GP.
Make key file from server ossec in the format ip_address.key.
Copy them to folder in server windows and share this folder.

or very simple you user script to deployment this soft when your computer startup